# Shifting data to first available cell (not row) in a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet to monitor inventory. I have a script in the sheet to copy values of rows with data and paste to the first available row on another sheet and then clear the content. This leaves holes in my data on the original sheet. I want to consolidate all my data up to the first available cells in a column so there would never be empty rows between rows with data. Unfortunately, I can't do the same thing I do with the other sheet, as I have certain columns in my row which have formulas that need to remain (Sum formulas to figure weight, etc). If I grab the entire row, it messes up my formulas or the formulas mess up the script (row is not available because it contains a value). So basically what I have is this:

```
Sheet1 name = 'CURRENT MONTH' 
Sheet2 name = 'SHIPPED INVENTORY'
```

Total Range with data on Sheet1 =    `A11:W61` 
Ranges with data that needs to shift up = `A11:O61, R11:S61, V11:W61` 
Ranges with formulas that cannot shift = `P11:Q61, T11:U61`

I've searched what I could but either I cannot word my dilemma correctly or the answers are beyond my skill level and I can't make them work for me. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't ever use cell functions so I'm not familiar with them.  But when you delete a row don't the indices get readjusted?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you are moving your information from one sheet to another, this code copies the entire row to the first row of the inventory sheet:

```
function myFunction ()
{
  ...

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var month_sheet = ss.getSheetByName ("CURRENT MONTH");
  var shipped_sheet = ss.getSheetByName ("SHIPPED INVENTORY");

  var month_values = month_sheet.getDataRange ().getValues ();
  for (var i = 11; i < month_values.length && i <= 61; i++)
  {
    if (test_value) // This is a row you want to move to the other sheet
    {

      // Create a row in the SHIPPED INVENTORY sheet,
      // and copy the full row into it
      shipped_sheet.insertRowAfter (1); // Assuming a header row
      var shipped_row_1= shipped_sheet.getRange (2, 1); // Get second row in file
      var month_range = month_sheet.getRange ((i + 1), 1, 1, month_sheet.getMaxColumns ());
      month_range.copyTo (shipped_row_1);

      // Now move everything else up
      moveRangeUp (month_sheet, "A", i, "O61");
      moveRangeUp (month_sheet, "R", i, "S61");
      moveRangeUp (month_sheet, "V", i, "W61");
      i--; // Since everything moved up, check this row's new information
    }
  }

  ...          
}

function moveRangeUp (sheet, first_col, row, last_col_row)
{
  var from_a1Notation = first_col + (i + 1) + ":" + last_col_row;
  var to_a1Notation = first_col + (i);
  var copy_range = sheet.getRange (from_a1Notation);
  var to_range = sheet.getRange (to_a1Notation);
  copy_range.copyTo (to_range);

  // After shift up, delete last row of data, since it is also moved up
  // Always assuming that the last row is row 61
  var delete_a1Notation (first_col + "61:" + last_col_row);
  var delete_range = sheet.getRange (delete_a1Notation);
  var delete_range.clear ();
}
```

Comment: I haven't had a moment to try this out yet, but I'm trying to move single occupied cells to the first available cell in the column.  I can't do complete rows as it overwrites my formulas, at least so far in what I've tried.  I will test and tweak this to see if I can get it to do what I need to.  Thank you!